# Bind the Height of the Listbox inside the StackPanel to StackPanel`s height

Tags: wpf, binding, elementname

I want to bind the Height of the ListBox to the Height of the StackPanel so the ListBox stretches itself Vertically so the green area is not visible anymore.

When there is no item in the listbox its hidden.
When there is item > 1 the ListBox must be stretching itself to the add/del buttons so the add/del buttons are always at the bottom of the stackpanel(dont want to use dockpanel for that)

How can I do that? I get no binding erros?

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stack" Background="Green" DataContext="{Binding DocumentViewModelList/}" Orientation="Vertical" >
    <ListBox SelectionMode="Single" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDocumentViewModel,Mode=TwoWay}"
        Height="{Binding ElementName=stack,Path=Height}"                                               
        Width="Auto"
        Focusable="True"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Name="documentListBox"
        BorderThickness="1"                                                
        ItemsSource="{Binding DocumentList}"
        Visibility="{Binding ElementName=documentListBox,Path=HasItems, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        <!--<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>                                                  
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}" />                                                      
        </Style>      
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>-->                                        
    </ListBox>                                                                                      
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a Grid instead of a StackPanel:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" 
      Background="Green" 
      DataContext="{Binding DocumentViewModelList}">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="0"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  ..... />

    <UniformGrid Grid.Row="1"
                 Rows="1"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Button Content="Delete" />
        <Button Content="Add" />
        <Button Content="Open" />
    </UniformGrid>

</Grid>
```

The ListBox simply takes up the entire space of the first row, while the UniformGrid takes up the bottom row with only the space it needs (and makes the buttons all the same size as a bonus).

No need for hard-coded width/height values (or any bindings for height/width), and no value converters needed.

Comment: @Wako wako :P nice nice nice!

Answer (score 0):

To implement the selective height (if has items x else y) use a value converter... also, I think height will be NaN so try ActualHeight (Bad practice but might work)... use a tool like snoop to see the values!

Is their a specific reason you are using a stackpanel? I grid will work better (StackPanel only give the min space needed where a grid can give as much space as needed)?

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <ListBox Grid.Row="1" />
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
    <!-- Buttons -->
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```